# "Undefined variable: cust (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ONLINE1EXAM\resources\views\internal\customer.blade.php)"

Tags: php, laravel

I am try to pass array in `customer.blade.php` ,i know the `web.php` file is not the right place to do that but i see some video in that the array is passed like this ,`web.php` file nad `customer.blade.php` file

```
Route::get('customer', function () {
    $cust=['ganshyam','ram','mohan']; 
    return view('internal.customer' ,['cust=>$customer']);
});
```

customer.blade.php

```
<h1>Our customers</h1>
<ul>

@foreach($cust as $cust1)
    <li>{{$cust1}}</li>
@endforeach

</ul>
```

> Undefined variable: cust (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ONLINE1EXAM\resources\views\internal\customer.blade.php)

Comment: You have a typo. The closing quote is in the wrong place. `['cust=>$customer']` should be `['cust' => $customer]`. Currently, you're just passing an array containing the literal string`'cust=>$customer'` as an indexed array.

Comment: Just noticed that you're also populating `$customer` while passing `$cust` to your view.

Answer (score 1):

Update the following line of code:

```
return view('internal.customer' ,['cust=>$customer']);
```

So that it looks something like following.

```
//Please note that, name of your array is $cust
return view('internal.customer' ,['cust'=>$cust]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change $cutomer to $cust

```
Route::get('customer', function () { 
    $cust=['ganshyam','ram','mohan']; 
    return view('internal.customer' ,['cust'=>$cust]);
});
```

Comment: You should remove the back ticks around `$cust` in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable name you want to pass on the view is the same on what you have on your controller, you can just do this:

```
$customers=['ganshyam','ram','mohan']; 
$fruits=['mango','strawberry','grapes']; 
$vegetables=['eggplant','cucumber','carrot']; 

return view('internal.customer', compact('customers', 'fruits', 'vegetables'));
```

Then on your balde file:

```
<h1>Our customers</h1>
<ul>

@foreach($customers as $customer)
   <li>{{$customer}}</li>
@endforeach

</ul>
```